# Paypal Integration in iOS does not show login window first time?

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal

I want to implement Paypal payment gateway in my project but the paypal login window is displaying after 3 or more consecutive executions of the below IBAction please let me know what's wrong with the below code

```
-(IBAction)initializePaypal:(id)sender
{
    [PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T"forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];
    status = PAYMENTSTATUS_CANCELED;
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].shippingEnabled = FALSE;
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled = FALSE;

//for a payment with a single recipient, use a PayPalPayment object

    payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init] ;
    payment.recipient = payPalValue.merchantEmail;
    payment.paymentCurrency = payPalValue.currencyCode;
    payment.description = payPalValue.itemName;
    payment.merchantName = @"By Post";
    payment.subTotal = payPalValue.amount;

    [[PayPal getPayPalInst] checkoutWithPayment:payment];

}
```

Comment: are you getting stuck at the "Checking this Device" text?

Comment: No nothing happens at all,

Comment: I see. You are using the old SDK. Can't help I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling paypal intialization when button is clicked. It takes 3-4 seconds. You have call intialization before that and check initializationStatus and in else call again as shown in below code

```
-(IBAction)initializePaypal:(id)sender
{
    if ([PayPal initializationStatus] == STATUS_COMPLETED_SUCCESS)
    {
        status = PAYMENTSTATUS_CANCELED;
        [PayPal getPayPalInst].shippingEnabled = FALSE;
        [PayPal getPayPalInst].dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled = FALSE;

        //for a payment with a single recipient, use a PayPalPayment object

        payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init] ;
        payment.recipient = payPalValue.merchantEmail;
        payment.paymentCurrency = payPalValue.currencyCode;
        payment.description = payPalValue.itemName;
        payment.merchantName = @"By Post";
        payment.subTotal = payPalValue.amount;

        [[PayPal getPayPalInst] checkoutWithPayment:payment];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"initialization failed");// show alert or "reintialising paypal"
    }
}
```

Comment: After clicking I am waiting for 5 to 6 seconds for response but no response at all on a single click

Comment: have you checked initializationStatus? it will clear the problem. what status you are getting. and intialize paypal in didload.

Comment: @GaganKumar let me know if you need anything else? or answer is helpfull to you.

Comment: actually I am not working on that project right now,As you can see that I have asked this question 15 days ago. So I will try this later and let you know it worked or not.